# Fixed element overlays scrollbar of parent

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, fixed

I have a problem with fixed element and scrollbar. Is there any way to move fixed element behind scrollbar of parent element? Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwq5afgp/1/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.scrollable-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.very-long-content {
  height: 5000px;
}

.fixed-element {
  background-image: url(http://space-kids.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jupiter.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section class="scrollable-container">
    <section class="very-long-content">
        <div class="fixed-element"></div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Set `z-index: -1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a negative `z-index` to `.fixed-element` (or, in general, make sure it's smaller than the one of `.scrollable-container`, which defaults to `0`). Be aware that this will make the content of `.scrollable-container` be displayed in front as well (including the content of `.very-long-content`).

I would recommend you, if possible, not to nest fixed elements, because [they are always positioned relative to the screen's viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values).

Answer (score 0):

**Image which shows**
[image: Fixed-element]

This how your fixed-element should be like

```
.fixed-element {
  background-image: url(http://space-kids.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jupiter.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -100px;
  top: calc(50% - 150px);
  width: 300px;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```